# "Porting" an alpha strategy to a different benchmark

Tags: portfolio-optimization, mean-variance

I'm reading about the mean-variance optimization of active portfolios. A bit of prior background from the book I'm reading: the author discusses the mean-variance optimal portfolios without cash, which amounts to solving the following optimization problem:

Maximize: $w^Tf - \frac{1}{2}\lambda (w^T\Sigma w)$, subject to $w^Ti = 1$,

where $w$ and $f$ are column vectors of the weights and returns (respectively) of all securities, $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix, $\lambda$ the risk tolerance and $i = (1, ..., 1)^T$ is just a column vector of all $1$'s. The optimal weight vector turns out to be:

$$w^* = \frac{\Sigma^{-1}i}{i^T \Sigma^{-1}i} + \frac{1}{\lambda}\frac{(i^T \Sigma^{-1}i)\Sigma^{-1}f\ -\ (i^T \Sigma^{-1}f)\Sigma^{-1}i}{i^T \Sigma^{-1}i}$$

Next, while considering an active portfolio, we can decompose the portfolio into benchmark and active weights - $w = b+a$. Since $w^T i = 1$ and $b^T i = 1$, $a^Ti = 0$. So the optimization problem in this case is:

Maximize: $a^Tf - \frac{1}{2}\lambda (a^T\Sigma a)$, subject to $a^Ti = 0$. The optimal active weight vector is:

$$a^* = \frac{1}{\lambda}\frac{(i^T \Sigma^{-1}i)\Sigma^{-1}f\ -\ (i^T \Sigma^{-1}f)\Sigma^{-1}i}{i^T \Sigma^{-1}i}$$.

So far so good. Now the interpretation given in the book is as follows:

> ...it (the active weights) is independent of the benchmark.
>   Consequently, the expected active return or alpha and the active risk
>   are also independent of the benchmark.

I can't understand how this claim follows from the equations above. Secondly,

> It is therefore theoretically feasible to utilize or port it on any
>   benchmark. In other words, two active equity portfolios managed
>   against two different equity benchmarks could have the same active
>   weights. For instance, the active weights of an equity portfolio
>   managed against S&P 500 index could be the same as the weights of a
>   long-short market-neutral hedge fund. This is the idea behind the
>   so-called portable alpha strategies, i.e., the alpha or excess return
>   generated from a strategy can be ported onto another different
>   benchmark.

Could someone please explain what is meant by "porting" on to a benchmark? How can you port an $n$-dimensional active weight vector meant for an index with $n$ stocks on to another benchmark with $m \neq n$ stocks?